# rcli tools uses rostime or system(wall-time)?

Tags: ros2

I'm trying to collect data from ros2 commands: ros2 topic hz & ros2 topic bw.
I'm able to get data perfectly for any topic. But i just want to know whether these rcli tools or commands mentioned above uses rostime or system (wall-time) in their calculation?

If answer to above question is rostime. Then how can I get that specific "rostime at which the frequency or bandwidth" are calculated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ROS2 CLI tools such as `hz` that you mentioned supports using ros time and wall time. That said, for current releases it will default to using ros time unless wall time is specified.

The time itself is provided via the `Node` class and the clock it uses can be retrieved with `get_clock()`. See the following example:

```
from rclpy.node import Node
some_node = Node(“NodeName”)
node_clock = some_node.get_clock()
```